# mysql server installation prevented by mariadb

Tags: mysql

I have mysql client and I am trying to install mysql server

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

but this is what I get

> mariadb-server-10.0.20-1.fc21.x86_64 already installed and latest version

why does mariadb get in the installation of mysql server installation ?
how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mariadb](https://mariadb.org/) is an enhanced version (a fork) of vanilla mysql.  It uses the same source code by Monty and the guys that original created mysql. This all started after their concerns that [mysql would stay free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) under the GNU license when SUN, who had acquired mysql, was acquired by oracle.

With that being said, mariadb and mysql use the same port number, data directory, and Process among other things.  As long as mariadb is installed on your system you will not be able to install vanilla mysql. First [uninstall mariadb](https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-completely-uninstall-mariadb-from-a-debian-7-server/) and then try and install mysql again.

Comment: i was able to download mysql client couple days ago or is mysql client on a different port? , isnt there a way around this? I am not sure why i have mariadb i did not install it but maybe its used somewhere as a dependency to something else , any idea about the effects of unistalling it ? @BK435

Comment: Since you have it installed, you installed it at some point. Uninstalling mariadb will have an effect of you not having mariadb any more. MySQL client is not the same thing as MySQL server. What are you trying to achieve? Any MySQL client is able to "talk" to mariadb or percona mysql, they use the same protocol.

Comment: @N.B. :) ofcourse uninstalling will mean i dont have it any more . I dont want to uninstall it because as i said this mariadb might be a dependency or needed somewhere . I want to install mysql server to have a mysql localhost db .

Comment: As this answer tells you, mariadb **is** MySQL. It just has a different name, but it comes with enhanced functionality - most of that functionality won't matter to a regular user, so in your case it's the same thing whether you use MySQL from Oracle (avoid it) or MariaDB / Percona - all three are the same thing essentially. Nothing depends on it directly, it's not a library. If you uninstall it and install MySQL, you're basically settling for a worse version of the database. My question remains - what are you trying to achieve? Use a GUI program to visualize data in DB?

Comment: @N.B.  ii understand now , yes I have mysql workbench i was trying to add a localhost connection but did not work out so i thought maybe because i dont have mysql server

Comment: We spammed BK435's answer (which is correct btw.) but - yes, you do have MySQL server, to check if it runs use `lsof -i :3306` and it will show you the program that listens on that port. It probably didn't work because you supplied wrong auth credentials, or it could be that localhost isn't resolvable by your machine - try `127.0.0.1`. Another problem might be that mariadb isn't listening on all network interfaces. It would be easier to help you if you included more information about the error(s) you get.